# what is the implementation of spark thrift server

Tags: apache-spark, thrift, apache-spark-sql

How does the Spark Thrift server translate standard sql to underlying nosql databases like Cassandra? is Data Frame involved?

is the thrift server code part of the open source code?

Comment: You could open that code and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the Spark Thrift server translate standard sql to underlying
>   nosql databases like Cassandra? is Data Frame involved?

Spark Thrift server is simply another Spark application. It has main method and runs as usual Spark application. Check
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/HiveThriftServer2.scala#L69
It works with NoSQL/SQL/ using Spark SQL, including DataFrames. Talking about Cassandra interoperability, it's implemented in DataStax Cassandra connector, you can check code here:
https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/cassandra

> is the thrift server code part of the open source code?

Yes, it's a part of Apache Spark main repository: https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/hive-thriftserver

Comment: Thank you. I will go over the source.